# How can I send an email from php on certain conditions without user intervention?

Tags: php, email, cron-task

I am doing an online course interface. The courses have modules (or chapters) that activate on certain dates. When the date comes, and a module activates (activation dates are stored in a database and differ from class to class), I would like to send an email to all students, telling them that the module is now active. I suppose that the server should run this separately from the website.. like cron jobs but set automatically using the dates from the database..

How could I approach that?

Comment: A cron'd script could do it. Make it check all not-yet-active modules against the current date, and if their date is past, send the email and mark them as active. Or something like this. Note that this question doesn't fit this site well, as it's very open and opinion-based. There are probably many ways to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! You just gave me a great idea! :) I know the question is open, it's a general approach question, not specific code related but you really helped me, and, I think that, if others would want to do something like this, it will help them also :)

Comment: Happy it helped :)